# Why isn't my furnace igniting?

Tags: hvac, furnace, pilot-light

I noticed cold air from my Carrier 58SS furnace. The main burners were not lighting. The pilot flame was strong, but yellow.

When I tapped on the gas valve, the pilot shut off. I removed the pilot tube to clear any possible blockage.

I also removed and replaced the 3-Wire (used previous sparker)
When everything was back together, switched on the power. The inducer fan ran for 4 minutes. No spark. I shut it off the power.

What might the problem be?

Comment: Does the control board have an error code light?

Comment: Your furnace has both a hot surface ignitor and a pilot?

Comment: I just had an issue with my furnace not lighting and it turned out to be a dirty filter causing a pressure/airflow sensor to stop the unit from lighting.  Changed the filter and it was all good.  Check the basics first!